# Publishing items not showing in Publish Queue

Tags: core-service

When publishing a lot of items (1000+) with the Core Service as single transactions (ala Powertools publisher) there is a noticeable delay of when the items show up in the publishing queue.  Is it because of the performance of the database or the memory usage?  Maybe something I can monitor with perfmon in the DB or Server?

Here is the code:

```
var readoptions = new ReadOptions();

PublishInstructionData instruction = new PublishInstructionData
{
    ResolveInstruction = new ResolveInstructionData() { IncludeChildPublications = false },
    RenderInstruction = new RenderInstructionData()
};

// ...

client.Publish(publishItemArray, instruction, target.ToArray(), GetPublishPriority(publishItem.Priority), readoptions);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah we've found that for large publishers there have been problems.   The PT team did talk about checking the length of items to publish and processing them (calling client.Publish) for every 200 or so.  this has shown to give a performance boost.

Unfortunately I've not had time to implement.. but I do have some logic that hasn't been checked in - if you have some time to continue this development?